# Popup in style of ContentControl not updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a ContentControl with a style that contains a popup that wraps a textbox. I know it sounds a little confusing but I will post some code below. When the caps lock key is on the popup is shown, but when the window is dragged the popup does not move with it.

I need to figure out how to update the location of the popup in they style.

This ContentControl is used on both a window and UserControl so that is why I am trying to address this in the style.

This question differs from some of the others as I am trying to solve it in the style and not code.

The content control:

```
public class ShowCapLockWarningControler : ContentControl
{

    static ShowCapLockWarningControler()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ShowCapLockWarningControler), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ShowCapLockWarningControler)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowMessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(Reflection.GetPropertyName<ShowCapLockWarningControler>(i => i.ShowMessage), typeof(bool),
                                    typeof(ShowCapLockWarningControler), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool ShowMessage
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowMessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowMessageProperty, value); }
    }

    public ShowCapLockWarningControler()
    {
        IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged += (s, e) => RecomputeShowMessage();
        PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => RecomputeShowMessage();
        PreviewKeyUp += (s, e) => RecomputeShowMessage();
    }

    private void RecomputeShowMessage()
    {
        ShowMessage = IsKeyboardFocusWithin && Console.CapsLock;
    }
}
```

How its used:

```
<controls:ShowCapLockWarningControler Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource CaplockWarning}">
    <PasswordBox  Width="150" Name="PasswordBox" PasswordChanged="HandlePasswordChanged" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                 KeyDown="HandlePasswordBoxEnterPressed"/>
</controls:ShowCapLockWarningControler>
```

The style in the style dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="CaplockWarning"  TargetType="{x:Type controls:ShowCapLockWarningControler}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ShowCapLockWarningControler}">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="Presenter"/>
                    <Popup Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Presenter}" Name="BalloonPopup"  AllowsTransparency="True"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ShowMessage}"  >
                        <!-- Visual of the popup-->                      
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I am looking to take care of this in the style because there is no place to add code behind and bindings.

Comment: Why are you keeping the popup. Close it on the lost focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window.LocationChanged event`, `Popup.Placement = AbsolutePoint`, `Popup.HorizontalOffset`, `Popup.VerticalOffset` .

In the sample below, `Popup` appears when `ContentControl's` `Loaded` event is fired. And we change relevant `Popup` properties when `Window` changes its location.

Code :

```
<ContentControl x:Name="CntCtrl" Height="35" Content="Some content" Loaded="CntCtrl_Loaded_1"/>

<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=CntCtrl}" Placement="AbsolutePoint"  x:Name="Popup1">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>item1</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Popup>
```

Code :

```
private void Window_LocationChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    Point ptb = CntCtrl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    Popup1.HorizontalOffset = ptb.X;
    Popup1.VerticalOffset = ptb.Y + CntCtrl.Height;
}

private void CntCtrl_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup1.IsOpen = true;
    Point ptb = CntCtrl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    Popup1.HorizontalOffset = ptb.X;
    Popup1.VerticalOffset = ptb.Y + CntCtrl.Height;
}
```

Comment: Its not completely in the style but it will do. Thank you.